# Dynamic Subdomain Routing With NextJS

Tags: subdomain, next.js, wildcard-subdomain, dynamic-routing

How can the Dynamic Sub domain routing feature be implementing in NextJS?

Example: If a user comes with username `abc` in site `xyz` then he can access his
site on `abc.xyz.com`

Also, if the user have `abc.com` domain then he can point `abc.com` to `abc.xyz.com`
So in future if someone opens `abc.com` then `abc.xyz.com` is served. And in URL
also the `abc.com` is shown.

I have investigated few plugin in NPM like vhost and wildcard-subdomains but not sure that is right way to take on this issue.

The vhost requires changes in system `hosts` in local system and wildcard-subdomain solves the issue purely with routing.

The Local System Setting I have customized **Server.js** With Code Which Works Temporarily, but does't seems to be a solution which can be used in production :

**Server.js**

```
  ...
    if (pathname === "/demo.demo.com") {
          app.render(req, res, "/demo.demo.com", query);
    }
    ...
```

And in **_app.js**

```
static async getInitialProps(appArgument) {
   ...
    return {
      ...
      renderFrom: "demo.demo.com"
    };
  }
```

Also in my host I have `demo.demo.com` point to `localhost`.

The site works for me in `demo.demo.com:3000` but how to generalise it in production scenarios
with Database and `CNAME` Records and add/change CNAME Record automatically with User Action.

Comment: I dont see how next.js can be related to automatic change or add a CNAME record.

Comment: To perform the above solution, we need to have a host added to local system. The equivalent of host in local System in Internet is CNAME record.

Comment: Yes i know, but next.js is not meant to do such things

Comment: @Nico: Are you referring that Dynamic Subdomain Routing can not be done with NextJS as I am using NextJS for my application and this is the requirement. The Solution works but how to make it generic with DB and Server Properly.

Answer (score 6):

On [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) (the creators of Next.js), we support [Wildcard Domains](https://vercel.com/docs/custom-domains#wildcard-domains) out of the box. Within Next.js, you then only need to read the Domain from the headers of the incoming request, parse it and then respond with the right content.

I hope that was helpful!

Comment: Is there no other way of doing this? I am thing of writing a custom server.

Answer (score 5):

I just found this blog post https://demo.vercel.pub/platforms-starter-kit, which was published 6 days ago.

It announces https://platformize.co/, a product that does just that.

> Multi-tenant applications serve multiple customers across different subdomains/custom domains with a single unified codebase.
>
> For example, this blog is a multi-tenant application:
>
> - Subdomain: demo.vercel.pub
> - Custom domain: platformize.co (maps to demo.vercel.pub)
> - Build your own: app.vercel.pub
>
> Another example is Hashnode, a popular blogging platform. Each writer has their own unique .hashnode.dev subdomain for their blog:
>
> - eda.hashnode.dev
> - katycodesstuff.hashnode.dev
> - pit.hashnode.dev
>
> Users can also map custom domains to their .hashnode.dev subdomain:
>
> catalins.tech → pit.hashnode.dev

Comment: This is their official recommendation now