# How do I route a subdomain to a NextJs route

Tags: next.js, dns, vercel

I have a NextJs app with 2 routes (`/` and `/blog`) configured as:

- pages/index.tsx
- pages/blog/index.tsx

When I deploy them on vercel, everything works fine but I want to have a subdomain for `/blog` like `blog.example.com`. So whenever an user goes to `blog.example.com`, I want to redirect them to `example.com/blog`.  So in my registrar I added `blog` as `cname` and in my vercel, I added that subdomain. But the problem is vercel doesn't show any options for this redirection. It only allows redirections to other domains or to a different git branch but not to a domain *with a route*.

Basically I want to route `blog.example.com` to `example.com/blog`on my vercel config. But Vercel doesn't allow me to add a route along with the domain.

In my registrar, my dns is configured as following:

```
example.com       A      <some ip>
blog.example.com  CNAME  cname.vercel-dns.com.
www.example.com   CNAME  cname.vercel-dns.com.
```

So what are my options? I know I can just create 2 different projects, one for `/` and one for `/blog` and use [monorepos](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/monorepos) but it seems like an overkill as my `/` webpage is very simple.

Edit:
Found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64427803/7361941) where they suggest using wildcard domains on vercel and then in the NextJs app, parsing the url, and then doing the redirection... which is fine, I guess. But it seems a bit hacky? Shouldn't this redirection logic be done in the cloud management side and not within my webapp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Subdomain Routing With NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590811/dynamic-subdomain-routing-with-nextjs)

Comment: @Rob oh yea, [wildcard domains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64427803/7361941) seems like an option. But I don't want to bring the parsing logic into my nextjs app.

Comment: In addition to Wildcard Domains, you can also setup [domain redirects](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/custom-domains#redirecting-domains) within Vercel. Wouldn't that work for your use case?

Comment: @juliomalves unfortunately they don't support forwarding paths to the redirected domain. It's a very plain domain to domain redirecting. Anyhow I found a [workthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72932918/7361941)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like I was approaching it from the wrong end. The registrar, in my case google domains, allows [domain forwarding](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en). So I removed my sub domain from the `cname` and added it here. Problem solved.

[image: ss from google domains]